# Disable proxy for entire application?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, proxy

Ever since upgrading to Visual Studio 2010, I'm running into an issue where the first web request of any type (WebRequest, WebClient, etc.) hangs for about 20 seconds before completing. Subsequent calls work quickly. I've narrowed down the problem to a proxy issue.

If I manually disable proxy settings, I don't experience this delay:

```
Dim wrq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url)
wrq.Proxy = Nothing
```

What's strange is that there are no proxy settings enabled on this machine in Internet Options. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to disable proxy settings for my entire project in one shot without explicitly disabling as above for every web object.

The main reason I want to be able to do this is that I'm trying to use an API (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/) which uses web requests, but does not provide any way to manually disable proxy settings.

I have found some information suggesting that I need to add some proxy information to the app.config file, but I get errors building my program if I make an edits to that file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Internet settings are stored on a per-user basis.  So, for example, in a web app the Internet settings would depend on the account that the associated app pool was using ... if you remoted in to the server in question, your settings would not necessarily be the same.  I point this out only because it has tripped me up more than once :(

Answer (score 6):

Brent - that's the correct solution : adding a [defaultProxy element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings) to your application's configuration file.

So for a website, it's the web.config. For an .exe application, it's .config.

And those settings are also correct :-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
            <proxy/>
            <bypasslist/>
            <module/>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you for your tip. This change worked for me, but only ONCE! How could it be possible? What I did: 1. Change web.config as suggested; 2. iisreset => it worked, no proxy anymore. 3. changed it back to `<defaultProxy />`; 4. iisreset => it didn't work (as expected); 5. did 1, 2 again, but this time it didn't work, it keeps using the proxy. Does this make any sense? What should I check? What could I forget?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of turning off the proxy setting altogether you can try using the bypasslist to turn it off for the servers that you're having problems with.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx for details and a sample.

If you're having problems changing the app.config I suggest posting the errors and possibly the app.config as well.

Comment: Well, I gave editing the app.config another try, and I'm not getting the error messages anymore. Here is the code I had to add to disable proxy settings for the application:

  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

Thanks!