# remove proxy setting from App.Config in runtime ? ( C# .Net 4 )

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, app-config

I'm writing a C# application with.net 4.0.
Is there any way that I can remove something ( like a proxy setting ) from App.Config in runtime ?
if yes than is there any way that I can put it back again ?

Farzad

Comment: Most of the settings in the config file can be overridden programatically. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

YOu can disable the proxy settings manually by using this ....

I hope this link will clearly explains you......[disable proxy for entire application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657094/disable-proxy-for-entire-application)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
            <proxy/>
            <bypasslist/>
            <module/>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```