# How to set no to proxy in app.config. in .NET 4.0 WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, httpclient

Based on the articles that I read, in order to improve the HttpClient performance in a WPF application, one of the things we need to do is set no to proxy. I have done this in code.

What I would like is 
1) Set No to proxy via app.config instead of code.
2) And if possible also allow Fiddler to intercept the network traffic ( even though we set no to proxy)

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable proxy for entire application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657094/disable-proxy-for-entire-application)

Comment: I did use that post earlier and have configured app.config with the following:   <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
Now when I startup it fails in the bootstrapper and the stack trace does not point to anything meaningful. Maybe my config is correct? or Missing some references? I did make a reference system.net assembly